# ffmpeg conversion is very slow - How to optimize it?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am cropping and splitting a video of size 13476*1500 into 4 parts, below is the filters. The conversion is very very slow! Is there a faster way to convert the videos? please help!

And also i want to know if there is an alternative way to do the same job or with handbrake.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=2691:1200:0:0[out1];[0:v]crop=4036:1200:2691:0[out2];[0:v]crop=2691:1200:6727:0[out3];[0:v]crop=4036:1200:9418:0[out4]" -map [out1] -map 0:a out1.mp4 -map [out2] -map 0:a out2.mp4 -map [out3] -map 0:a out3.mp4 -map [out4] -map 0:a out4.mp4
```

Comment: Not really – your input file is huge. This process will be largely CPU- and memory-bound. What are your system specs? And yes, you can use Handbrake to crop video, but I'm not sure you can automate it that easily.

Comment: @slhck thank you for responding, the file size is 150mb, 8 sec video file. I have intel i5 6300u running at 2.5 ghz.

Comment: The original file size in MB does not matter, but when it is decoded you'll have uncompressed 13476⨉1500 px frames loaded. Do you care about what output codec / format is used?

Comment: yes output format is .mp4

Comment: That was not my question. Do you care about which format it is? Do you have any particular requirements in terms of codec, file size, quality, …?

Comment: i am no expert on the codec, upon googling, i think H.264 would be a good choice. But yes if the output size is same or little more its fine, but no compromising for quality.

Comment: You can add `-preset fast` or `-preset faster` before each output file, but I doubt that you will see significant improvements, since most of the time will be spent processing the cropping.

Comment: An insignificant optimization would be to stream copy the audio instead of re-encoding it, but it qualifies as an optimization. Add `-c:a copy` before each output. Otherwise, there is not much you can do other than use a faster preset, use a faster CPU, encode on multiple machines, or investigate if hardware accelerated decoding and/or encoding such as [nvenc](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro) would help.